# Integer Break Intuition

Tags: algorithm, math, dynamic-programming

LC: https://leetcode.com/problems/integer-break/

The key observation that unlocks a non-DP solution is the fact that for any integer `n`  greater than `4`, it has the property such that `3 * (n - 3) > n` which means breaking it into two integers `3` and `n - 3` makes the product larger while keeping the sum unchanged.

If `n - 3` is still greater than 4, we can break it into `3` and `n - 6`,  resulting in `3 * 3 * (n - 6)`
, and so on, until we cannot break it (less than or equal to 4) anymore.

I was just wondering more from an academic perspective, why this is true/valid?

Comment: Why is what true?

Comment: In general, if `a <  b <= c <  d` are such that `a + d = b + c`, then `a * d < b * c`. This is a very "geometric" fact, which can be shown algebraically but is better remembered as "if a rectangle and a square have the same perimeter, then the square has a larger area". In particular, when `1 < 3 <= n - 3 < n`, we have `1 * n < 3 * (n-3)`.

Comment: Or more generally "if two rectangles have the same perimeter, then the rectangle which looks more like a square has the larger area".

Comment: I recommend asking these types of questions on https://math.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: Algebraically you can see that `(A + e)(B - e) = AB + e(B-A) - e²`, so if `A < B` and `0 < e < B-A`, then `(A + e)(B - e) > AB`. In words, if A and B are far apart, then "bringing them closer" by adding e to A and removing e from B will increase the product.

Comment: If you only want to prove that `n > 4` implies `3 * (n - 3) > n`, you can just manipulate these equations and notice that `3 (n - 3) > n` is equivalent to `2n - 9 > 0`, which is equivalent to `n > 4.5`.

Comment: I don't think what's in your question is a proof, and the "key observation" is just one part of a proof. I've added a complete proof as an answer -- perhaps that's what you were asking for.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that 3(n-3) > n for n>4 shows that it is never correct to break up n into pieces larger than 4 (otherwise you could cut off a piece of size 3 from it to increase the product). [It's easy to prove, since 3(n-3) = 3n - 9 which is larger than n when 2n-9 > 0, or n>4½. For integers, that's the same as n>4.]

Without loss of generality you have no pieces of size 4, since they're equivalent to having 2 pieces of size 2.

You can also see that you never have more than 2 pieces of size 2 (otherwise you could replace 3 of them with 2 pieces of size 3 to get a bigger product).

Clearly you have no pieces of size 1 (except for the case n=1), since you can incorporate them into any other piece to increase the product.

So for n>1, there can be 0, 1, or 2 pieces of size 2, and the rest are of size 3.

That leaves the only viable decompositions for n>1 as 3x3x3...x3 (when n=0 mod 3) or 2x3x3x3...x3 (when n=2 mod 3) or 2x2x3x....x3 (when n=1 mod 3).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed breakdown! Just wondering how this sort of observation can be discovered during an interview haha...

Comment: The question has nothing to do with programming, it's just maths. Not sure why you would be asked this in an interview unless it's for a role that needs some maths.

Comment: I mean it's on Leetcode so it must have been asked at some point in a coding interview...